# How to customize (Rails) Devise routes ending with 'new', 'edit', and so on?

Tags: devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, customization

Here it is the devise part of my config/route.rb :

```
devise_for :admin_utilisateurs, :path_names => { :sign_up => 'enregistrer',
                                                 :sign_in => 'connexion',
                                                 :sign_out => 'deconnexion',
                                                 :password => 'mot_de_passe',
                                                 :unlock => 'deverouiller'},
                                :path => 'identification'
```

This result in the following `rake routes` :

```
        new_admin_utilisateur_session GET    /identification/connexion(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
            admin_utilisateur_session POST   /identification/connexion(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
    destroy_admin_utilisateur_session DELETE /identification/deconnexion(.:format)           devise/sessions#destroy
           admin_utilisateur_password POST   /identification/mot_de_passe(.:format)          devise/passwords#create
       new_admin_utilisateur_password GET    /identification/mot_de_passe/new(.:format)      devise/passwords#new
      edit_admin_utilisateur_password GET    /identification/mot_de_passe/edit(.:format)     devise/passwords#edit
                                      PUT    /identification/mot_de_passe(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
cancel_admin_utilisateur_registration GET    /identification/cancel(.:format)                devise/registrations#cancel
       admin_utilisateur_registration POST   /identification(.:format)                       devise/registrations#create
   new_admin_utilisateur_registration GET    /identification/enregistrer(.:format)           devise/registrations#new
  edit_admin_utilisateur_registration GET    /identification/edit(.:format)                  devise/registrations#edit
                                      PUT    /identification(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                                      DELETE /identification(.:format)                       devise/registrations#destroy
       admin_utilisateur_confirmation POST   /identification/confirmation(.:format)          devise/confirmations#create
   new_admin_utilisateur_confirmation GET    /identification/confirmation/new(.:format)      devise/confirmations#new
                                      GET    /identification/confirmation(.:format)          devise/confirmations#show
             admin_utilisateur_unlock POST   /identification/deverouiller(.:format)          devise/unlocks#create
         new_admin_utilisateur_unlock GET    /identification/deverouiller/new(.:format)      devise/unlocks#new
                                      GET    /identification/deverouiller(.:format)          devise/unlocks#show
```

How can I change ?, for instance, the route :

```
/identification/deverouiller/new
```

into

```
/identification/deverouiller/nouveau
```

If I add `:new => 'nouveau'` into the `:path_names` hash, that does'nt work.

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [`rails-translate-routes` gem](https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes) could help with this. Check out the **I18n Routes** section in this blogpost by Fabio Akita : [Minimal I18n with Rails 3.2](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2012/07/24/minimal-i18n-with-rails-3-2/) for details about how to use the gem - in conjunction with devise - to translate to full URL to native languages.

Answer (score 2):

One solution which does not require using an additional gem consists in using a scope with a **path_names** option:

```ruby
scope path_names: { new: 'creer', edit: 'modifier' } do

   devise_for :users

end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments for more information.